# turning on Proxy Preserve Host breaks SSL proxy rule

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I have a third party SSL-enabled site that I have a proxy pass rule on my apache host. The page has relative links so I wanted to use the ProxyPreserveHost directive to keep the originating hostname in the URL whenever a user browsed other pages with the same relative web dir (/app), but when I turn it on all of the pages 404.

Below is my proxy configuration:

```
ProxyTimeout 300
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine On


#testing support 
ProxyPass /app https://example.custhelp.com
ProxyPassReverse /app https://example.custhelp.com
```

Comment: What's in your logs?

Comment: Just a standard 404 response: 10.3.42.65 - - [23/May/2013:09:52:23 -0700] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 404 191

Comment: Also, another proxy rule I have in place that goes to a plan HTTP hosted third party site works properly with the current rules in place. Is it a possible SSL issue? I would expect a 403 if that were the case...

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the client a 404 because the upstream server is sending a 404.  `example.custhelp.com` is the domain name it's expecting to receive; when being sent the same `Host` header that was sent in the request, it's not able to find content at that path to serve.

If the links in the page are indeed *relative*, and not *generated* based on the incoming `Host` header, then `ProxyPreserveHost` is irrelevant, since the client would see no change.

You might be looking for `mod_proxy_html`, instead?